# Move mass files and folders

Tags: 14.04, files, rsync

I have a lot of folders to move from old HDD to new SSD, but I don't know how to use the rsync utility, any help with it? I don't know how to move them and I fear the electricity will go out and lose my progress on moving and have to go all over, on Windows I had Teracopy but here I'm feeling lost!

Answer (score 1):

Luckily there is an easy to use utility to move the files and folders and it's called Grsync.
It has a graphical user interface and it's available in the Ubuntu software center, so installing it is easy.
Always happy to help the new guys.
PS: Search for questions before posting, OK?

Comment: I will give it a try and see, thanks for the advice anyway